# Eclipse CDT. Exclude from build is always grayed (and I cant include it of course)

Tags: eclipse, resources, eclipse-cdt

In the ECLIPSE CDT the checkbox "Exclude from build" is always grayed for some resources (but for most enabled).

[image]

Did anyone has this problem as well. Maybe someone knows the sollution.

Comment: Is it just displayed in gray by mistake, so that the value can still be changed? If not, which Eclipse CDT version are you talking about?

Comment: @howlger If I could change it, I would not ask this question :) It is actually Atollic Studio

Comment: See https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=72732&goto=227464&#msg_227464

Comment: @howlger +++ thank you very much. The folder for some reasons was not considered as source folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been [answered by James Blackburn in the Eclipse CDT forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=72732&goto=227464&#msg_227464):

> These settings are managed in: Project Properties > C/C++ General >
>   Paths and Symbols > Source Location
>
> If you have a look there you should see your source file excluded and
>   you have the option of changing the exclusion pattern.
>
> The way this works is that these settings are stored in the cdt core
>   model (so that they can be used by the indexer and such like) -- hence
>   being listed under C/C++ general, but are also used by the build
>   system when working out which files need to be built.
>
> Hope this helps,
>
> James